# R: get the indices of equal columns matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix with some columns that are equal. 
I would like to get the indices of that columns. 
For example, if the matrix is

```
0   2   1   0   2
0   1   5   0   1
4   9   4   4   9
6   14  -1  6   14
```

I would like to get something like `c(1, 4)` and `c(2, 5)`
I there a smart way of achieving this?

Comment: Maybe you have to provide further details because it seems to me that this question is exactly like the one you posted one hours ago.

Comment: Yes, actually it is similar, I am trying to get around the problem, still unsolved

Comment: @Ruggero Based on the solution I provided, I get a list with the indices `c(1,4)`, `c(2,5)` and `3` as list elements.  I don't know what is unsolved now.

Comment: @Ruggero In your previous question, you had columns that have the same value in different order and I guess you wanted to get the columns that are similar after `sort`.  So, my solution was based on that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution :

```
identical_idx <- function(i) which(colSums(mm[,i]==mm) ==nrow(mm))
unique(lapply(seq_len(ncol(mm)-1),identical_idx))

[[1]]
V1 V4 
 1  4 

[[2]]
V2 V5 
 2  5 

[[3]]
V3 
 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `dist`:

```
mat <- read.table(text="0   2   1   0   2
0   1   5   0   1
4   9   4   4   9
6   14  -1  6   14")
mat <- as.matrix(mat)

d <- as.matrix(dist(t(mat)))
d[lower.tri(d, diag = TRUE)] <- NA
which(d < 1e-16,  arr.ind = TRUE)
#   row col
#V1   1   4
#V2   2   5
```

Comment: And I can only reiterate: You have a kind of clustering problem and should use algorithms designed for this instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: no here OP is looking for **identical** columns. Using a distance or a clustering algorithm ( a measure behind the scene) will only group *similar* vectors.

Comment: @agstudy A distance algo can find identical columns (within floating point precision). I assume that they are still working on the same problem as in their last question and that is not about identical columns.